# SCSS Mixin Function for UL LI nested list

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, scss-mixins

I have UL li nested structure for tree and I wanted to write dynamic code using SCSS Mixin that left value can update accordingly. Here is my code

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Level 1: Item 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Level 2: Item 1</span></li>
      <li><span>Level 2: Item 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Level 3: Item 1</span></li>
          <li><span>Level 3: Item 2</span></li>
          <li><span>Level 3: Item 3</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Level 2: Item 3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Level 1: Item 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Level 1: Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
ul li{
  position:relative;
  margin:4px 0;
}
ul li span{
  display:block;
}
ul li span:before{
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:blue;
  z-index:-1;
}
ul li span{
  position:relative;
  color:white;
}
ul li span::before {
        left: -8px;
    }
    ul li li span::before {
        left: -48px;
    }
    ul li li li span::before {
        left: -88px;
    }
    ul li li li li span::before {
        left: -128px;
    }
    ul li li li li li span::before {
        left: -168px;
    }
    ul li li li li li li span::before {
        left: -208px;
    }
```

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/up638szn/16/)

Can you please help me to add dynamic left value using SCSS Mixin so that left value will update as per number of levels. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple mixin:

```
@mixin leftPosition($startingValue: 0, $increment: 40, $max: 10) {
    $selector: '';
    
    @for $i from 0 through $max - 1 {
      $selector: $selector + ' li';
      #{$selector} span::before {
        left: #{$startingValue - $i * $increment}px;
      }
    }
}
```

It takes few parameters:

- `$startingValue` is the first value for your `left` property. It defaults to `0`, but in your example you'd want `-8`.
- `$increment` is the incremental value you want, heree you want `40`.
- `$max` is the number of `li` you'll get.

You can use it like this:

```
ul {
    @include leftPosition($startingValue: -8)
}
```

And it will output:

```
ul li span::before {
  left: -8px;
}
ul li li span::before {
  left: -48px;
}
ul li li li span::before {
  left: -88px;
}
ul li li li li span::before {
  left: -128px;
}
ul li li li li li span::before {
  left: -168px;
}
ul li li li li li li span::before {
  left: -208px;
}
ul li li li li li li li span::before {
  left: -248px;
}
ul li li li li li li li li span::before {
  left: -288px;
}
ul li li li li li li li li li span::before {
  left: -328px;
}
ul li li li li li li li li li li span::before {
  left: -368px;
}
```

Of course, you can't get the value of `$max` from the *HTML*. It's a value you'll have to define yourself.

Comment: can you please tell me what is $selector variable. I am getting unknown word

Comment: This is what I tried from your code https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/up638szn/31/

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo when I formatted my answer. I've seen your fiddle, you shouldn't close the bracket after `$selector: '';`. This is just a variable that will equal to `li`, then `li li`, etc...

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar It might be the compiler of Js Fiddle that is outdated, see codepen: https://codepen.io/AmauryH/pen/LYmJxRM

Comment: Thank you so much Amaury Hanser. I tried this solution and working as expected. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
li:nth-child(2) {
   padding-left: 48px;
}
```

with the value in brackets you can select the li and and with padding-left you set the left space of li and you don't need the span

Comment: Actually I want that span in my structure because my actual structure is more complex I have just shared required piece of code